# Environment.getExternalStorageState() returns MEDIA_REMOVED on an HTC that has available memory

Tags: android

In my app, im trying to check whether the user has connected their phone to the pc as a drive, so I can warn them to disconnect it because I need access to the storage.

It works fine on all 4-5 devices that I've tested on, except this **HTC Desire X phone, Android 4.0.4** . It has no SD card, but there is about 2 gb of some storage available for writing.

Here is the code that I use

```
private void checkStorage() {
    // Get the external storage's state
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    Log.d("STATE", state);
    if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        // Storage is available and writeable
        externalStorageAvailable = externalStorageWriteable = true;
    } else if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
        // Storage is only readable
        externalStorageAvailable = true;
        externalStorageWriteable = false;
    } else {
        // Storage is neither readable nor writeable
        externalStorageAvailable = externalStorageWriteable = false;
    }
}
```

So when I run it, the logcat debug tag returns:

```
removed
```

According to documentation:

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#MEDIA_REMOVED

"Storage state if the media is not present."
```

How can I modify this code so it detects the presence of a memory that is available for use?

Now, there is another thing. On this phone, when I try downloading an image from the browser, Im not allowed to, and I get the following message:

```
No SD card
An SD card is required to download <filename>
OK
```

Is there something wrong with the phone or is this normal? How do I make my app work on this phone?

EDIT: Furthermore, if I am able to get past this, how do I write files to the storage? Here's my code that does that and works on other devices:

```
File directory = null;
    File file = null;

    try {
        directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), 
                Utils.getWritableDiectory(Locale.ENGLISH));

        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }

            file = new File(directory, "data.json");
```

Comment: How do you know there is 2GB available?  Where is it available?  It really sounds like this device does not have an external storage which is currently available to apps.

Comment: when I open ES File explorer, there are some folders in the mnt/ folder, for example DCIM where camera stores images and a Downloads folder which has a Bluetooth folder with some songs in it. Is it possible to run an app that requires some kind of storage on such a device?

Comment: Have you tried to reboot your device?

Comment: Yes I have tried that :)

Comment: have you tried this: Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

Comment: yes, its in the code in my question :)

Comment: Maybe this phone treat external built-in storage as SD card and when it's connected to PC storage is unavailable for your app. Have you tried different USB modes? Switching them is usually available from notifications.

Comment: Have you checked on any other internal storage phones i mean to say the devices which do not have external storage support

Comment: @J.K. have you find any solution ?